# XCode 5.0.1 Documentation Locked on Login Screen

Tags: xcode

Am I the only one who's still having this issue in XCode 5?

As far as I know the same thing happened for XCode 4 before, then Apple fixed it?

The symptom is: in XCode -> Documentation and API Reference. After typing in the correct Apple ID and password, clicking "Sign In", the page just flashes. Then the 2 text-boxes became empty again.

! [Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOUGL.png)

I'm pretty sure:

1. My Apple ID has been registered as a developer.
2. My Password is correct. (I tried the wrong password, there will be a red message to tell you "wrong password" something on the screen, not like what I described above.)

Comment: One more thing to add: I recently upgraded XCode, then this happened.